# How to change variable in struct?

Tags: c, struct

I am writing a c program to read the title, authors, journal and published year of an article (actually it is a homework). I know I should use fgets() to read the information and hold in struct. However, I was stuck in updating one of the variable in struct, what should I do?

That's my code. I know it looks strange and probably gets wrong as I'm not quite understand how to create a new article and update the title in function. I have try strcpy but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _article{
  char title[100], author[100], journal[100];
  int year;
} Article;

Article create_article(char *title, char *author, char *journal, int year) {
  // create a new article based on the parameters
  // remember to return the article
  Article new_article = new_article;
  
  return new_article;
}

Article update_title(Article article, char *title){
  // update the title of the article based on the parameters
  // remember to return the updated article
  Article updated_article = article;
  strcpy(updated_article.title ,title);
  return updated_article;
}
```

I have skip the print function and there is the main function

```
int main(void){
  Article article, new_article;
  char title[100], author[100], journal[100];
  int year;
  fgets(article.title, 80, stdin);
  fgets(article.author, 80, stdin);
  fgets(article.journal, 80, stdin);
  int len1 = strlen(article.title);
  int len2 = strlen(article.author);
  int len3 = strlen(article.journal);
    if (article.title[len1-1] == '\n')
      article.title[len1-1] = 0;
    if (article.author[len2-1] == '\n')
      article.author[len2-1] = 0;
    if (article.journal[len3-1] == '\n')
      article.journal[len3-1] = 0;
  scanf("%d", & article.year);
  print_format_full(article);
  
  update_title(article, title);
  fgets(new_article.title, 80, stdin);
  print_format_simplified(new_article);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With the definition `Article new_article = new_article;` what do you think will happen? How will copying the uninitialized object `new_article` into itself do any kind of initilaization?

Comment: As for `update_title`, you pass the `article` argument *by value*, meaning that the *local* variable `article` will have a *copy* of the original structure used in the call. The function then *returns* the updated structure, but you ignore that returned object.

Comment: oh, it's a typo. It should be Article new_article; But I'm not quite sure what the Article create_article function mean (as the structure is given), is it simply copying the Article like new_article = article and related to the Article update_title function?

Comment: Your create_article function has a bunch of parameters. Can you come up with an explanation of why they are provided?

Comment: I'm not a fan of gratuitous typedefs (eg, I would recommend eliminating the typedef altogether), but if you're never going to use the `_article` name, you might as well just typedef an anonymous struct.  eg `typedef struct { ... } Article;`

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with `Article new_article = new_article;`
You are assigning your new struct to herself, thats why it doesnt work.
Try to simply declare a struct in your main and assign to each member the values you read from your file.

Comment: Can I simply write `fgets(new_article.title, 80, stdin);
  strcpy(new_article.author, article.author);
  strcpy(new_article.journal, article.journal);
  new_article.year = article.year;`  that creates a struct `new_article` with scanning the updated title and copy parts of variable in struct `article` in main? Will it work?